# How to remove link in MD file?

Tags: gitlab, markdown

In my project on gitlab I have some text in *.md files that looks like URL link, e.g. "asp.net" and by default it processes as clickable link. I want it to be processed as regular text. How to do this?

Now I realize .md files process different ways in webpages. Dillinger.io render asp.net as link and stackoverflow and gitlab as plain text.

[image]

Comment: I tested adding `asp.net` in a `.md` but it's not clickable. Could you show an example of file content and a screenshot ?

Comment: I did .md file first time with online editor dillinger.io, which show preview for "asp.net" as clickable link. Now I can see gitlab process such markdown as plain text. Thank you, @NicolasPepinster

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

##### put it between two `back-tick`s

`asp.net` => `asp.net`

### Better Way

Put a `ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER` character after the dot:
'‌' as you can see it is not visible. It is also called `half-space` character. It is usually used in Arabic texts to separate characters:
سلام => س‌ل‌ا‌م

You can use it like:
asp.&#8204;net => asp.net (it is not a link)

`&#8204;` is the code for `half-space` character.